# Join Query in string format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, inner-join

Hi i'm trying to join tables together when loading my session variable Below is my code

```
Dim cmdstring As String = "SELECT * FROM Users.Location_Code = Location.Location_Code =
Medical_Equipment.Location_Code WHERE Staff_No = @StaffNo"
```

I am attempting a 3 table join this data will then be presented on a grid view. Is it possible for a join to be made here in this string?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction where i can find an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. But you need to have proper SQL `JOIN` syntax. Your current SQL query doesn't make sense. It should look about like this (I assume that Staff_No is a column in Users table) :

```
Dim cmdstring As String = _
            "SELECT * FROM Users u " & _
            "INNER JOIN Location l on l.Location_Code = u.Location_Code " & _ 
            "INNER JOIN Medical_Equipment m on m.Location_Code = u.Location.Location_Code " & _
            "WHERE u.Staff_No = @StaffNo"
```